# Vertical align glyphicon in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have a glyphicon as such:

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up glyphicon-large"></span>
</div>
```

```css
.glyphicon-large {
    min-height: 260px;
    font-size: 35px;
    width: 1em;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -0.5em auto 0px;
}
```

The glyphicon won't align to the center, vertically. When I open firefox, inspect element, and toggle off/on the `top 50%` rule, it suddenly works. How come?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Browser Bug Explanation

#### According to [MDN on `top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top):

> For *relatively positioned elements* (those with `position: relative`), it *specifies the amount the element is moved below its normal position*.
> **Note**: Percentage is applied as a percentage of the height of the element's containing block

#### According to [W3 on `top`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-top):

> For *relatively positioned* boxes, the offset is with respect to the top edges of the box itself (i.e., the box is given a position in the normal flow, then offset from that position according to these properties).
> **Note**: Percentages refer to height of containing block

#### Here's my guess:

I think what's happening is that when the [browser is first rendering the visual tree](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm), and sees `top:50%;`, it looks to the parent to set the height.  Since no height has been specifically applied, and it has not loaded any child contents, the height of this div (and all divs) effectively *starts off as zero* until otherwise indicated. It then pushes down the glyph by 50% of zero.

When you toggle the property later, the browser has already rendered everything, so the calculated height of the parent container is provided by the height of its children.

#### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example

**Note**: This doesn't really have anything to do with Bootstrap or Glyphicons.  In order to avoid a dependency on bootstrap, we'll add `top: 1px` that would have been applied by the `.glyphicon` class.  Even though it is overwritten by `50%`, it still plays an important role.

Here's a simple set of parent/child elements:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

In order to simulate the toggling the property in a more repeatable fashion, we can just wait two seconds and then apply a style in javascript like this:

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("child").style.top = '50%';
},2000);
```

#### Example 1 ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/tu9mpyeg/))

As a starting point, let's recreate your issue.

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    
    /* For Visual Effects */
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
#child {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    top: 1px;
    
    /* For Visual Effects */
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    
}
```

Notice that as soon as you resize the window, the browser will repaint the screen and move the element back to the top.

[image: example1 screen]

#### Example 2 ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/tu9mpyeg/11/))

If you add `top: 50%` to the child element, nothing will happen when the javascript adds the property because it won't have anything to overwrite.

#### Example 3 ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/tu9mpyeg/12/))

If you add `top: 49%` to the child element, then the DOM does have something to update so we'll get the weird glitch again.

#### Example 4 ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/tu9mpyeg/14/))

If you add `height: 50px;` to the container instead of the child, then the `top` property has something to position against right from the get go and you don't need to use toggle in JavaScript.

---

## How to Vertically Align

If you just wanted to know how to vertically center something consistently, then you can do the following:

The trick to vertically centering text is to set the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) equal to the container height.  If a line takes up 100 pixels, and the line of text online takes up 10, then browsers will try to center the text within the remaining 90 pixels, with 45 on the top and bottom.

```css
.glyphicon-large {
    min-height:  260px;
    line-height: 260px;
}
```

#### [Solution in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Z9ZFr/)

Comment: You can definitely use `top` with `relative`. It may not do what you expect it to do, but in fact it's clearly defined what it should do and it does exactly that.

Comment: @Jasper, good point, you're right.  I updated the answer with an explanation about using `position: relative` with `top: %`

Answer (score 1):

Tried centering a glyph icon that was inside an H1 tag, that was taking a while - so I discovered that you can actually change the font size and colour inside the SPAN tag contaning the glyph.

Thus:

```
<h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="font-size: 24px; color: #108db7;"></span>&nbsp;Mes Messages</h1>
```

actually worked out for me.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried ? :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up glyphicon-large" style="vertical-align:middle"></span>
```

Comment: Note, the question that is being asked here is why the applied style doesn't work on **page load**. But it **does work after manually toggling off and on the `top: 50%` property** using a browser developer tool. (@Ricoxor)