# Bootstrap Glyphicon Vertical Align

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, glyphicons

Is it possible, to re-positioning the glyphicon so that it's displayed in the "human-eye"-center of the following Text?

To explain, what i mean:

[image: edited_screenshot]

I tried "large-glyphicon", but it doesnt make a difference. Is there some built-in function to solve this, or which CSS could i add manually.

.

Code-Snippet for better viewing:

```html
<link href="http://holdirbootstrap.de/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://holdirbootstrap.de/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" style="width:1200px;">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">
                    Lunatics Car Club Austria
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Über den Verein</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Wir sind ein bei der Bezirkshauptmannschaft Vöcklabruck <strong>eingetragener Club/Verein</strong> mit dem offiziellen Vereinsnamen &quot;Lunatics Auto Club Österreich&quot;.<br>
                          <br>
                        </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Vereinsinformationen + Downloads </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Mitglieder</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Wir zählen 45 aktive Mitglieder mit XX Autos und insgesamt 5200PS aus dem Großraum Vöcklabruck.                        <br>
                          <br>
                        Unser Vorstand besteht aus 6 Mitgliedern.<br /><br /></p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Mitgliederprofile + Fahrzeugdetails</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Der Weg zu uns</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Hast du Lust, dich unserem Club anzuschliessen, und teilst unsere Begeisterung für Autos sowie das Clubleben gleichermaßen?<br>
                          <br>
                          Zögere nicht, und bewirb dich!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Kriterien + Formular</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try assigning the same `min-height` and `line-height` to `glyphicon-large`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24887062/4252369) are the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quickest way to set this up would be to change your titles to 2 `span` tags and then pass a `.tblcell` class that uses the `table-cell` CSS property.

HTML

```
<h4>
    <span class="tblcell glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="tblcell">Über den Verein</span>
</h4>
```

CSS

```
.glyphicon {
    position: static;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.tblcell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I also suggest not using the '& nbsp;' character you are using for padding and just use an actual CSS padding (which is what I did in your glyphicon class)

Here is a [JS.Fiddle with your example](http://jsfiddle.net/gsxf5zwu/). The change has only been applied to your first title. Hope that helps.